# Change in Enthalpy for Constant volume process

Tags: thermodynamics

For an isochoric process
$$\Delta H = \Delta U + V\Delta P$$

Which can also be written as

$$\Delta H = C_v\Delta T + V\Delta P$$     assuming ($C_v$ is constant)

Therefor to calculate $\Delta H$ we need 6 values $C_v$, $T_1$, $T2$, $V$, $P_1$, $P_2$

However a book I was reading they claim that we need only $C_p$, $T_1$, $T_2$ which means
$$ \Delta H = C_p\Delta T$$
even for an isochoric process which I think is incorrect because the process is not isobaric.

Comment: If you're okay with $\Delta U = C_V\Delta T$ (even if the process undergone isn't constant-volume), you should be okay with $\Delta H = C_p\Delta T$, because the reasoning is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For an isochoric process
> $$\Delta H = \Delta U + V\Delta P$$
> Which can also be written as
> $$\Delta H = C_v\Delta T + V\Delta P$$     assuming ($C_v$ is constant)

The second equation applies only to the ideal gas. (The general relation is $\Delta H=C_P\Delta T+V(1-\alpha T)\Delta P$, where $\alpha$ is the constant-pressure thermal expansion coefficient.)

(I’m using finite-difference $\Delta$ to match your question; as Chet notes below, the equations are then correct only if the coefficients, including the material properties, are constant.)

Again for the ideal gas, $V\Delta P = nR\Delta T$, and $C_V+nR=C_P$, so $\Delta H=C_P\Delta T$ always holds for the ideal gas, which we can also obtain from the general equation by noting that $\alpha\equiv\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P=\frac{1}{T}$.

Comment: We should also be using differentials and not $\Delta$'s.  The equations are incorrect in terms of deltas, unless the deltas are infinitesimal or the coefficients are temperature-and pressure independent.

Comment: Great point; edited to emphasize.